# How can i string a single image url to my flutter app from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i'm trying to string a image url to a flutter networkimage widget from my firebase database document .

```
Image( image: NetworkImage('eventurl'),
```

can anyone help me with this plz.

```
body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container (
            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            child: Center(child: Text('FREATURED EVENT',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 10.5,
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ),
          Image( image: NetworkImage('eventurl'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have the URL and want to show in UI, to this, use the `Image` widget with factory method `network`, like this:

```
...Container(child: Image.network('https://YOURURLIMAGEHERE.COM')),
```

To get the image, put your code into a function that returns a Future and is async, like below:

```
Future<MyDocument> readDocumentFromDatabase() async {...access firebase and retrieve data }
```

After that, use `FutureBuilder` widget to call this function, example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: readDocumentFromDatabase(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.hasData == false) { return CircularProgressIndicator(); }

    return Container(child: Image.network(snapshot.data.eventUrl));
},);
```

to see how to implement `readDocumentFromDatabase` see https://medium.com/47billion/how-to-use-firebase-with-flutter-e4a47a7470ce

[]s

Comment: i trying to pass the image url using snapshot method that way i can update the image from the firebase backend

Comment: Can you show more of your final code and describe what problem is occurring?

Comment: Now I see... but, where is your snapshot code? (StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder widget)

Comment: I Updated my comment with some explication... Try to solve now with your business logic :D